# Thrash-cluttered input fields check

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, frameworks

I want check some input fields for non-real, cluttered entries like "test", "user", "asd", "asdasd", "qweqwewq". I know it is not possible for all combinations because it has sooo many combinations. But maybe I can handle some basic thrash words. So my question is any js or php library exist for this problem?

edit: these fields are `name` `surname` `username`

Comment: Do you mean input validation? What are you trying to validate? usernames? Please be more specific on your end-goal.

Comment: Oh yes it's name, surname, username.